# Group of list turn into integer output

Tags: python, list, math, integer, gaussian

How to turn a group of list into integer output from this code?

```
matrix0 = [[3, -13, 9, 3], [-6, 4, 1, -18], [6, -2, 2, 4], [12, -8, 6, 10]]
vector0 = [-19, -34, 16, 26]

matrix1 = [[3, 2, -5], [2, -3, 1], [1, 4, -1]]
vector1 = [0, 0, 4]

gaussy(matrix0, vector0, 4)
gaussy(matrix1, vector1, 3)
```

i've got an output like this, i wanted to turn it into integer like [3,1,-2]...

```
The solution vector is [3.0000000000000004 ,0.9999999999999991 ,-2.0000000000000013 
                       ,0.9999999999999996 ].
The solution vector is [0.9999999999999999 ,1.0 ,1.0000000000000002 ].
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
lst = [3.0000000000000004 ,0.9999999999999991 ,-2.0000000000000013
                       ,0.9999999999999996 ]
lst = [round(elem) for elem in lst]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, -2, 1]
```

So this is how your final code should look like:

```
matrix0 = [[3, -13, 9, 3], [-6, 4, 1, -18], [6, -2, 2, 4], [12, -8, 6, 10]]
vector0 = [-19, -34, 16, 26]

matrix1 = [[3, 2, -5], [2, -3, 1], [1, 4, -1]]
vector1 = [0, 0, 4]

out_lst1 = [round(elem) for elem in gaussy(matrix0, vector0, 4)]
out_lst2 = [round(elem) for elem in gaussy(matrix1, vector1, 3)]
```

Comment: I tried to run the code and it says 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @FairuzAmira Does the `gaussy()` function have a return statement? Is the return being reached?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) functions:

```
rounded = map(round, gaussy(matrix0, vector0, 4))
```

And to convert back into a list:

```
rounded = list(rounded)
```

These statements could then be combined into:

```
rounded = list(map(round, gaussy(matrix0, vector0, 4)))
```

Notably, this is a worse solution than list comprehension (as shown in Sushil's answer) because it requires a conversion from a map object to a list object. The performance difference is likely negligible, but these are the two most common methods of applying a function to an iterable.